# Closing with Outsideclick on DialogFragment not working Android

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have a cutstom `DialogFragment` to show a message to the user:

```
public class MensajeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    TextView mTvMensaje;
    TextView mTvTitulo;
    Button mBtnAceptar;
    Button mBtnCancelar;            

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mensaje_dialog, null);
        mTvTitulo = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        mTvMensaje = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);
        mBtnAceptar = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);
        mBtnCancelar = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);

        mTvTitulo.setText(getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.bundle_titulo), ""));
        mTvMensaje.setText(getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.bundle_mensaje), ""));
        mBtnAceptar.setText(getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.bundle_aceptar), ""));
        mBtnCancelar.setText(getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.bundle_cancelar), ""));    

        builder.setView(dialogView);

        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        return builder.create();
    }


}
```

But when I reach the `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`, I am getting `NullPointerException` beacuse the `getDialog()` is returning `null`.

What am I doing wrong? I want to close the dialog when the user clicks outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **DialogFragment**, dialog won't be initialized on onCreate of **DialogFragment**. 
I believe DialogFragment by default closes when user clicks outside it.You don't have to declare it explicitly. If you still want to call this function, then **DialogFragment** has a function called

```
 DialogFragment.setCancelable(boolean)
```

EDIT

If the above code doesn't work, you can try calling

```
 getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

inside onCreateView as Dialog object will on be initialized on **getLayoutInflater** during onCreateDialog. So by the time it reaches onCreateView dialog object will be initialized.

Comment: thanks for the answer. With that code is still doing nothing when I click outside the popup

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if this works for you.

Comment: @DiieBarcia Glad I could help :)